# Delinearization in whitebox techniques

Tags: des

I'm reading through [Chow et al.'s paper](http://crypto.stanford.edu/DRM2002/whitebox.pdf) and [Link et al.'s paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/025.pdf).

There's a part I don't understand about Delinearization.

They convert some steps of AES/DES into a Matrix, then divide the matrix in 8x4 matrices and use look up tables to do the multiplications. But for the XOR they also use look up tables.

What is the use in that? It's pretty easy to see, even through a look up table, that we're doing simple XORs here.